# Slow plot for integral involving FractionalPart and sine

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning

I have defined this function:

```
f[x_]:=1/(1+Sin[FractionalPart[x]])
```

Then I tried to plot it using this code

```
Plot[Integrate[f[t],{t,0,x}],{x,0,2}]
```

It finally plot it, but it takes about 4-5 minutes to do it. There is a way to speed up similar plots, that involve commands as `FractionalPart`?

---

EDIT: I observed that changing `Integrate` by `NIntegrate` the plot speed up a lot, but Im not sure how accurate is the numerical integration to trust in the result of the plot.

Anyway I will like to know if there are other approaches to this problem using the symbolic integration. Thank you.

Comment: Since you'e plotting over a (necessarily) limited domain: `Assuming[0 < x < 2, Integrate[PiecewiseExpand[1/(1 + Sin[FractionalPart[t]]), 0 < t < 2] // Evaluate, {t, 0, x}]]`

Comment: Could avoid repeated symbolic integrals: `f[x_?NumberQ] := 1/(1 + Sin[FractionalPart[x]])
Plot[NIntegrate[f[t], {t, 0, x}], {x, 0, 2}]` One could further improve by keeping track of prior quadrature results and only adding increments.

Comment: As a comment, looking at the function: `Plot[1/(1 + Sin[FractionalPart[x]]), {x, 0, 10.7}]` The integration will be `Assuming[x > 0, 
 IntegerPart[x]*Integrate[1/(1 + Sin[x]), {t, 0, 1}] + 
  Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, FractionalPart[x]}]]` which is somthig like manual using PiecewiseExpand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DSolve` to calculate the symbolic integral over a finite interval.

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_] := 1/(1 + Sin[FractionalPart[x]])

F = y /. First@DSolve[{y'[x] == f[x], y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 2}]

Plot[F[x], {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It's reasonably fast:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Addendum: There is a reason I thought to try this. Events were added to `DSolve` a couple of versions ago, and these are used in discontinuity processing.  What I imagine happens is this.  When you've got an integrand with a standard discontinuous function, `DSolve` will split up the intervals and feed simple, continuous integrands to `Integrate[]`.  It then adds up the results and pieces them together.  At least that's how it seems when this trick works.  I'm not familiar with the internal implementation.*

Comment: this works, thank you.

Comment: one last question, why you used the command `/.` in the definition of F?

Comment: @Masacroso You're welcome, but why did you change the function after I answered? -- `DSolve` returns a rule `y -> func`, but we need `func` to do the graph.  You could use the newer `F = DSolveValue[..]` instead, but in my own work, I usually want the rule until the problems are completely worked out.